# React Native read cookie

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm using [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) for authentication. In the React Native app, I need to know whether the user is logged in (to redirect them to the proper screen).

Instead of storing an `isLoggedIn` flag in `AsyncStorage`, is there a way for me to detect the presence of the cookie (set by `passport`) directly (like `document.cookie` in browser)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a 3rd party module. This one - https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies

Then you can do:

```
CookieManager.get('http://example.com')
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('CookieManager.get =>', res); // => 'user_session=abcdefg; path=/;'
  });
```

to figure out the cookie for the domain